# Python virtualenv can`t work through OneDrive

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have my project stored on OneDrive. It sometimes works on my pc and laptop both of which have Windows 10. The project on both is in the same directory- `C:/OneDrive/code/etc...`

When I use virtualenv and download different packages, it works fine, but when I use my laptop nothing works at all (same applies the other way around). I get the following error:

> Could not import runpy module ImportError:
>
> No module named 'runpy'

What can I do to fix this problem on my laptop and PC? Anyone experiencing a similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this. OneDrive - and similar systems like Dropbox - are meant for sharing documents. They are not meant for code, and even less for installed libraries.

Store your code in a version control system like git, and push it up regularly to a host like Github. Then on each of your computers, clone the repo and install the dependencies locally inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a virtualenv synced with OneDrive ('pip' was no more recognized as a command for example).

I solved it by creating a **symbolic link** inside my OneDrive directory of a virtualenv I created outside. Like this, your drive provider can not modify/optimize/etc. your local files but they will be synced.

You can create a symlink with Windows cmd:

```
mklink /D "C:\...\OneDrive\...\target_dir\venv" "C:\...\source_dir\venv\"
```