# Can I create, store and run Python projects/scripts from a cloud storage network drive?

Tags: python, cloud

I've almost run out of space on my C: and I'm currently working for myself remotely. I want to purchase cloud storage that will act as a mounted drive, so that it can do the following:

- Store all of my Python projects along with any other files
- Run my Python scripts on VS code (or any IDE) straight from the drive
- Create virtual environments for my Python projects that will be stored on the drive
- Set up APIs, from Python scripts stored on this drive, to other programs (eg GA or Heroku) so I can push and pull data as required

I just purchased OneDrive thinking I'd be able do this but according to the answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082883/python-virtualenv-cant-work-through-onedrive) it's not a good idea. [This article](https://www.cloudwards.net/how-to-set-up-a-cloud-network-drive/) is describing the exact behaviour that I'm after and pCloud looks like a good option, given it's security, but I can't find much resource on it's compatibility with Python.

Google Cloud, AWS and Azure are all out of my price range and look too complex for what I'm after. My cloud computing knowledge is fairly limited but I was wondering if anyone has any experience of running scripts in Python from the cloud (from pulling data from a warehouse to hosting an application in the public domain) that isn't using one of the big cloud computing companies?