# Virtualenv seems to be active but really don't on MAC

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv called env on my directory...After activating:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

I see that it is activated...(env)
I have installed some libraries on the virtual env, and i can see that they ares installed on their folders, but calling...

```
pip list
```

The libraries that Appears on the list are not the libraries installed on the env.
Also calling a python file to execute, dontn run.
Therefore calling for checking the python version, don't match with the env python version.

[image]

I have tried to reinstall python and pip, but nothing happens

Comment: use `python -m pip list`

Comment: Seems that for some reason the virtual environment is not properly activated, as it should be version 3.9, but it prints out 2.7.16. Have  you tried recreating the venv?

Comment: would you give a try in the `terminal` ? to check if the terminal works okay?

Answer (score -1):

I work on a 2 macOS machines and I use iCloud for sharing my projects. I created the env on one macOS machine but the same env didn't work on the other macOS machine. That was the problem.

I created a requirements.txt on the first macOS machine, then I created a new env on the other macOS machine, loaded the requirements.txt, and it now works.

Comment: Writing this in big friendly letters: **PYTHON VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENTS ARE NOT PORTABLE!**

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest not using iCloud or Dropbox or and other similar file-syncing tools for working across different machines. Use a proper version control system, commit the `requirements.txt` (or whichever file your virtual env manager is using), then you will have to _always_ re-create the virtual environment on each machine. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082989/2745495